# Valid range of SQLite rowid?

Tags: sqlite, range, rowid

I'm making a wrapper of SQLite C API. And I want to return rowid as integer type. To mark error case, I need a invalid value of the rowid. Is there *invalid value* of SQLite rowid? Or all values in signed 64bit integers are valid for rowid? (because if it is, I have to choose another way to implement marking error case)

Comment: Here's spec about rowid: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Row IDs are 64-bit signed integers, so the maximum is 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL. But unless a negative or zero row ID has been entered explicitly, auto-generated row IDs are always greater than zero. If you can be certain that row IDs will always be generated automatically then zero or -1 would be safe values to for error status returns.

Thinking further, I realise that the `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid` API call returns zero if nothing has ever been inserted into the table, thus making zero a de-facto "invalid" row ID.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about explicit zero and negative values can be inserted. I will go something other mechanism. :)